# How to make nodes wait till the topology is defined

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm trying to implement a distributed algorithm on JBotSim. When I define the entire topology in my Main class, my algorithm works, but when I draw my graph on the canvas, it seems that first drawn nodes start the algorithm before I finish drawing my graph making my algorithm completely desynchronized.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the topology is started automatically, as in this example,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Topology topology = new Topology();
    new JViewer(topology);
    topology.start();
}
```

then the topology is already running when you add the nodes. Consequently, the `onStart()` method on each node is called as soon as you add it to the topology (which indeed, makes them start in a non synchronized way).

One solution here is to remove the call to `topology.start()` and start the topology manually once all the nodes have been added. This can be done in the context menu (right click > "start execution").